# How to stop undefined properties when getting data from API with axios in a React Component TS2532

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I am creating a specific product page for a store and getting data from a REST API with axios. I am in the process of converting this code from JavaScript to TypeScript. The problem is TypeScript is complaining that product is possibly undefined when I attempt to use its properties, such as the last line for stockStatus and in the JSX that I return.

```
interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
  brand: string;
  category: string;
  price: number;
  countInStock: number;
  rating: number;
  numReviews: number;
}

type RouteParams = { id: string };

const ProductScreen = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<RouteParams>) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState<Product | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get<Product>(
        `/api/products/${match.params.id}`,
      );
      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchProduct();
  }, []);
 
  const stockStatus = product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock';
  return (...);
}
```

I tried to use some way of ensuring the product data had been received and passing product to the following, but it didn't do much as it is undefined from the beginning:

```
export default function ensure<T>(
  argument: T | undefined | null,
  message = 'This value was promised to be there.',
): T {
  if (argument === undefined || argument === null) {
    throw new TypeError(message);
  }

  return argument;
}
```

Still I can't get around the object being possibly undefined, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By using `product?.countInStock` could be fine, if the product is possible to be `undefined` or `null` or other fake value. Or using [double question mark](https://indepth.dev/posts/1300/double-question-marks-typescript-3-7-nullish-coalescing)

Comment: This product will be undefined in first rendering pass if you want it to be define use something else in here: `useState<Product | undefined>(>>>undefined<<<);`

Comment: Yeah, I ended up solving this with instantiating my product with some dummy data and passing that to `useState<Product | undefined>(dummyProduct);`